# Problems with PrimeFaces's dialog component

Tags: java, jsf-2, dialog, primefaces

In my application, when the user clicks `Reply` to a comment, I will show a dialog for typing the message. Please see the picture below.

[image: Reply dialog]

As you can see, I have 2 problems with the dialog.

1. It is partially hidden by the `<p:layoutUnit>` on the right.
2. When I add the attribute `modal="true"` to the dialog, the dialog itself is also not accessible.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me some advice on how to tackle these problems.

Best regards,

Comment: On which browsers does this problem occur? (Looks like z-index bug of IE)

Comment: what primefaces version you using?

Comment: @Damian I'm using the lastest v3.3

Comment: @MattHandy I'm testing on Chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. To solve the problem, there are 2 things to do:

1. Add the attribute `appendToBody="true"` to the dialog component.
2. Bring the dialog out of the center `<p:layoutUnit>` and let it stand on its own outside `<p:layout>`.

One important thing to note is that if I add the attribute `style="z-index: 999 !important;"` to the dialog component, the dialog will appear normally. However, the text area will become unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

On Primefaces 5.x, it worked when I set `appendTo="@(body)"`